# Smoke too far from emitter

Tags: animation, smoke-simulation

I am doing a simple animation with smoke emitting from a circle on top of the chimney, but it is not behaving like it should.
I have initial velocity off.
The tank is going from right to left(forward)
[image: Smoke in wrong directions??]

Comment: Could you be more specific? Are you telling that the chimney moves from right to left and the smoke do the same, instead of going up and remaining in his X and Y position?
Are there constraints/parenting anything else that could move the smoke domain?
Is there wind or other phisic simulation (except for smoke)?

Comment: Sorry for unspecific question. The smoke has copy location constraint with the hull. There are no other forces. The smoke behaves funny, because it generates on spot, which it hasn't reached yet for first half of animation, and than no smoke is generated for the rest of the animation.

Comment: Ok! Thanks for the details... I'm trying to figure out how can it happen but at the moment I don't find a possible cause of it. Would it be possible for you to share the file or (if you can't) to share a similar file that replicates the problem?

Comment: Allright, so i fixed it. Instead of adding constraint to the emmiter itself, i made it a child of another object with the location constraint. Works just fine

Comment: Good! Glad to hear it.